# Common denominator example

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, fractions

Assuming sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+\alpha+1} =\frac{1}{0!(\alpha+1)}-\frac{n}{1!(\alpha+2)} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!(\alpha+3)}+\cdots+\frac{n!(-1)^n}{n!(\alpha+n+1)}$$
How does one derive generally, that this can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{n!}{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)(\alpha+3)\cdots(\alpha+n+1)}$$
I've got to derive this for smaller $n$, maybe $n=2,3,\ldots$ But i can't seem to get to derive it generally for all $n$. I don't think mathematical induction is the way here. Would someone help me out please?

Comment: I'd be interested to see if there's a combinatorial solution to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+\alpha+1} & = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \int_0^1 (-1)^kx^{k+\alpha}\,{dx}  \\&= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^kx^{k+\alpha} \,{dx} \\&= \int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{n}\,{dx}\end{aligned} $$

**Updated:** Denoting the integral by $I_{(\alpha, n)}$ and integrating by parts once, we get

\begin{aligned}I_{(\alpha, n)} & = \int_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha}}{(1-x)^{n}}\;{dx} =\frac{1}{\alpha+1} \int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{\alpha+1}\right)'(1-x)^{n}\;{dx} \\& = \frac{1}{\alpha+1}\cdot x^{\alpha+1}{(1-x)^{n}}\bigg|_{0}^{1}+\frac{n}{\alpha+1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha+1}{(1-x)^{n-1}}\;{dx} \\& = \frac{n}{\alpha+1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha+1}{(1-x)^{n-1}}\;{dx}  = \frac{n}{\alpha+1}~I_{(\alpha+1, n-1)}. \end{aligned}

So now we have a recursive formula.

$$\displaystyle \begin{aligned} I_{(\alpha, n)} & = \frac{n}{\alpha+1}~I_{(\alpha+1, n-1)} \\& = \frac{n}{\alpha+1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{\alpha+2}~I_{(\alpha+2, n-2)} \\&= \cdots \\&= \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 1}{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)\cdots(\alpha+n-1)}I_{(\alpha+n-1, 1)} \end{aligned} $$

But $ \displaystyle I_{(\alpha+n-1,1)}  = \int_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha+n-1}}{(1-x)}\;{dx} = \frac{1}{(\alpha+n)(\alpha+n+1)}$ thus $$ \begin{aligned} I_{(\alpha, n)} & = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 1}{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)\cdots(\alpha+n+1)} \\& = \frac{n!}{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)(\alpha+3)\cdots(\alpha+n+1)} \end{aligned} $$

Comment: Hoped that noone would really get to this, this is actually the way how I got to this formula. By starting at the integral $\int_{0}^{1}x^\alpha(1-x)^ndx$. I'm attempting to come to the formula $n!=\int_{0}^{1}{(-\ln x)^ndx}$ I assume i do not know the gamma function, neither the beta function so I don't want to use these.

Comment: @MichalDvořák So I just retraced your steps? It happens! I was just editing to add that the integral could also be calculated via other means - is that of any use to you?

Comment: Yea, you just did that. Well, if i used the beta function that would make no sense for me in the context because I am actually attempting to come to the gamma function, from there i get to the beta function and so on. But actually this gives me some nice connection between these. I didn't realise at first that this is the Beta Function.

Comment: @MichalDvořák I meant would a calculation of $\int_{0}^{1}x^\alpha(1-x)^ndx$ without the beta function be of use to you?

Comment: Well it could, do you have any other suggestions than replacing (1-x)^n with the binomial series?

Comment: @MichalDvořák See the updated answer.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, corrected some typos, thanks for that! This solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{n!}{(\alpha+1)\ldots(\alpha+n+1)}$$ is a rational function $F(\alpha)$ with simple poles at $\alpha = -1, \ldots, \alpha = -n-1$ and nowhere else, and $F(\infty) = 0$.  Therefore it has a partial fraction expansion of the form
$$F(\alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{c_k}{\alpha + k }$$
Now you just need to find the residues at each pole: $c_k = \text{Res}(F(\alpha); \alpha = -k)$.  You may use
the formula
$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{g(z)}{z-p}; z=p\right) = g(p)$$

Comment: I'm thankful for your answer but i would rather be intetested in elementary approach since I'm not familiar with complex analysis.

Comment: Are you familiar with partial fractions?  Given that the rational function $f(z)/\prod_k (z - r_k)$ has a partial fracton expansion of the form $\sum_k c_k/(z-r_k)$ where $r_k$ are distinct, it's easy to show that $c_j = f(r_j)/\prod_{k \ne j} (r_j - r_k)$.